# How to mark a ListItem in the Navigation Drawer as Highlighted

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, material-design

I am trying to Highlight the Drawer listitem when it is selected.

My Navigation Drawer ListView is:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true">
        .
        .
        .
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/drawer_view"
            android:layout_width="304dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left|start"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <!-- Your drawer content -->

            <ListView
                android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
                style="@style/NavDrawer"
                android:layout_width="320dp"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:layout_gravity="start"
                android:listSelector="@drawable/drawer_listview_background_selector"
                android:background="@color/icons"
                android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
                android:divider="@color/divider"
                android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Drawer List Item is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/text1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/drawer_listview_background_selector"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:textSize="14sp"
    android:textColor="@color/primary_text" />
```

Selector is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@color/primary" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/primary" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true" android:state_selected="true" android:drawable="@color/primary" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/normal" />
</selector>
```

In the onItemSelected method i am doing:

```
 // Highlight the selected item, update the title, and close the drawer
        mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
        mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
        setTitle(mPlanetTitles[position]);
        mDrawerLayout.closeDrawers();
        // mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(R.id.drawer_view);
```

Thing to note is that if i use

```
android:background="?android:attr/activatedBackgroundIndicator"
```

for the ListItem layout it is working very fine, but it applies Holo Color on my Android 4.4.4.

I have read most of the popular SO questions and tested but failed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add an `android:state_activated` `<item>` to your `<selector>`, choosing a color or drawable to use for the activated state.

Comment: Yes, that was missing, can we use a separate  `<selector>` to change the text color of the selected item or is there any better approach?

Comment: @ShajeelAfzal: Your `TextView` could use [a `ColorStateList`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/res/ColorStateList.html), which also uses `<selector>` syntax.